# Visualizing ZeroMQ network as graph in real time

Tags: python, graph, zeromq, pyzmq, rqt

I have a network of nodes in Python where I am using the ZeroMQ library with publish/subscribe messaging pattern to publish messages in a many-to-many fashion among other nodes. I want to be able to visualize the network of nodes as a graph where the edges represent the port connections between the nodes. I do not want to brute-force approach this; I want to run a python script that will automatically be able to achieve this on top of the zeromq nodes that I am already running. I want something that is similar to `rqt_graph` in ROS where I run [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph) and it automatically draws the nodes and connections.

I looked into Network Discovery with zeromq. I also found a page [Visualizing ZeroMQ networks as graphs](https://www.mail-archive.com/zeromq-dev@lists.zeromq.org/msg30807.html) but I am trying to figure out how to do this in my implementation.

Comment: This is not a question. You are describing a program you would like, but do not make it clear if you are asking for recommendations for existing tools to do this, or information about how to do this for yourself. In fairness, a request for recommendations would be off topic for stack overflow, as would requests for general "how do I build this advice". Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) info about how to ask helpful questions.

Comment: Apologies for the poorly framed question. I meant to ask for information on how to do this myself. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q :** *"I want to run a python script that will automatically be able to achieve this on top of the zeromq nodes that I am already running."*

While ZeroMQ is quite a powerful framework with many ports, security is its next most important design perspective, right after the ZeroMQ performance.

Without participating code "behind" the ZeroMQ links, your local-side is almost sure not to be able to "sniff" ZeroMQ links topology, right due to security and many-to-many ports in question.

In case you inject both sides of the ZeroMQ link with properly designed add-on code, you may easily maintain a map of current live-agents' connections, given the agents cooperate with your distributed ZeroMQ-aware cooperative monitoring add-on code.

Comment: "In case you inject both sides of the ZeroMQ link with properly designed add-on code, you may easily maintain a map of current live-agents' connections, given the agents cooperate with your distributed ZeroMQ-aware cooperative monitoring add-on code."
I read the ["Network Discovery" section on ZeroMQ documentation][1]. Is the above quoted portion referring to "Do user-level brute-force discovery"? I am looking into using message brokering to allow for large scale.
[1] https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter8/#Network-Discovery

Comment: No, it does not. All there mentioned cases are cases of sort of naive, (context-less or better own context-ignoring) almost a "blind cane" ticking alike,trial-error "search",whereas a due strategy is to build-in a self-adaptive, self-aware approach to setup, maintain and monitor ZeroMQ-agents' own interconnection meta-plane altogether with smart signalling of state/changes across this distributed agents' messaging & signalling metaplane all interconnect related telemetry to some "central"-(while internally distributed for resilience)-live-topology-state maintainer. This is the smart way ahead

Comment: I am interested in building the add-on code you described to maintain a map of current live-agents' connections and signal state changes across the distributed agents' messaging and signaling metaplane. Could you please guide me on how to get started with this approach? Do you have any recommended tools, libraries, or resources that can help me build the add-on code? @user3666197

Comment: The best tool, given using ZeroMQ already is the ZeroMQ - adding more, service meta-plane, signalling & telemetry connections, that form the cooperating inter-agents' signalling, explicit state-reporting, soft-signalling ISO-OSI-L9 level heartbeat / health / performance and other such related state/event/self-diagnosing data messages. Might want to start with a fabulous Pieter HINTJENS' original evangelisation of the Zen of Zero in his must-read book *"**Code Connected: Vol.1**"* mentioned / linked so many times in most of my posts gathered in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zeromq/topusers